# pip3 install pyautogui, error code 1

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, pyautogui

I can't install pyautogui i've tried everything, such as

```
pip3 install pillow
```

also followed the steps on the website [pyautogui website](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html). Here is the message i receive when installing.

```
root@alex-Ai:/# pip3 install pyautogui
Collecting pyautogui
Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.36.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/xauth.py", line 42, in __init__
    raw = open(filename, 'rb').read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.Xauthority'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-mvyjt7lg/pyautogui/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    version=__import__('pyautogui').__version__,
  File "/tmp/pip-build-mvyjt7lg/pyautogui/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
  File "/tmp/pip-build-mvyjt7lg/pyautogui/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 160, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 61, in __init__
    name, host, displayno)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 93, in get_auth
    return getattr(mod, modname).get_auth(sock, dname, host, dno)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 116, in new_get_auth
    au = xauth.Xauthority()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/xauth.py", line 44, in __init__
    raise error.XauthError('~/.Xauthority: %s' % err)
Xlib.error.XauthError: ~/.Xauthority: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.Xauthority'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mvyjt7lg/pyautogui/
```

@phd "sudo -H pip3 install pyautogui "  gives me this error

```
      alex@aimarket:/home$ sudo -H pip3 install pyautogui
      Collecting pyautogui
      Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.36.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-efkrhbdk/pyautogui/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    version=__import__('pyautogui').__version__,
  File "/tmp/pip-build-efkrhbdk/pyautogui/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
  File "/tmp/pip-build-efkrhbdk/pyautogui/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Xlib.display import Display
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Xlib'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-efkrhbdk/pyautogui/
```

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages. Post error messages instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: `pyautogui` does not work with **Ubuntu 17.10**, because `pyautogui` needs run X11, so you must go into the login screen of Ubuntu and click on the gear icon, in there you'll have two options which are `Ubuntu` or `Ubuntu on Xorg` click on the Ubuntu on Xorg, this will give you the **X11** feature which is needed. 
After that change, you can go back into terminal and run `pip3 install pyautogui`, this has solved it for me.

Answer (score 15):

`pip install python-xlib`

worked for me.

Comment: Still works in 2022

Comment: For a cron task I also needed `DISPLAY=:0` before the command

Answer (score 0):

`PyAutoGUI` on Unix requires [Xlib](https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib); the module [xauth](https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib/blob/master/Xlib/xauth.py#L39) tried to open `~/.Xauthority` i.e. `/root/.Xauthority` and filaed. It seems you're running X Window under non-root user or not running it at all.

Try to install `PyAutoGUI` for the user running X11. In case you really need to install as root install it preserving `$HOME` env var for that non-root user by running `sudo -H pip3 install pyautogui`.

If nothing helps point [XAUTHORITY](https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib/blob/master/Xlib/xauth.py#L35) env var to the file:

```
XAUTHORITY=/home/alex/.Xauthority pip3 install pyautogui
```

Comment: i updated the question. i am still running into the same problem. I also have a question about you mentioning "install for user running x11" what does this mean?

Comment: Under what account have you started X11? E.g., I start it under local user `phd`; when I need to run commands as root I use `sudo` or run a new terminal (I use `rxvt`) and login as root.

Comment: So I can across something similar that says " 17.10 uses wayland by default, not x11; thus, there is not an .xauthority file.

Also by default, root is not allowed access to your terminal; thus, can not run GUI programs." No sure if the that could be the problem. The "-H" command you suggested is supposed to work but I get the "no module named 'Xlib' " error . Hopefully that explains the x11 thing I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: Then `PyAutoGUI` is not for you. On Unix it works only with X11 as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I used `pyvirtualdisplay` and `pyautogui` and got the same error when I tried to package this to docker.
The `use_xauth = True` parameter helped me when creating the display.

```py
display = Display(visible=False, size=(800, 600), use_xauth=True)
```

Don't forget to install `xauth` as well

```sh
sudo apt-get install xauth
```