# python > Selenium > Traceback

Tags: python, selenium, traceback

[I tried a lot to fix Traceback Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK8GD.png)

The same code is working in Pycharm , But when I put it in replit.com , is shows this Error

```html
Python 3.8.2 (default, Feb 26 2020, 02:56:10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/xauth.py", line 43, in __init__
    raw = open(filename, 'rb').read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/.Xauthority'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 249, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 60, in __init__
    auth_name, auth_data = connect.get_auth(self.socket,
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 91, in get_auth
    return mod.get_auth(sock, dname, host, dno)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 103, in new_get_auth
    au = xauth.Xauthority()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Xlib/xauth.py", line 45, in __init__
    raise error.XauthError('~/.Xauthority: %s' % err)
Xlib.error.XauthError: ~/.Xauthority: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/.Xauthority'
```

**please help me**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install xauth
```

If it doesn't work there are other answers to the problem in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103873/pip3-install-pyautogui-error-code-1)